# Google Cloud Platform SD Installation - SSLHandshakeError

Tags: sdk, installation, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to install the [Google Cloud Platform SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/) on Windows 7 Enterprise. The GCP SDK installer is failing as there is an 'SSLHandshakeError' error message (screenshot below).

Please advise on recommended steps for troubleshooting this.

[image: GCP SDK Failed to install screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your machine might have an unauthorized Root CA certificate installed, such as [Superfish malware](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2015/feb/26/how-can-i-find-and-remove-superfish-and-similar-malware), which is causing this SSL handshake error.